# selenium c# chrome pdf validation

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, pdf

With Selenium using C#, I'm trying to validate a PDF pops up in an app. My code to click the Close (X) button at the top-right of the PDF works, but not the code to verify any elements for the PDF, such as:

```
//*[@id="plugin"]
```

Basically, I'm not able to access any elements in the separate Developer Tools browser that opens up after using Inspect on the PDF. The element for the PDF Close button, which I am able to access, is in a separate Developer Tools browser.

I've installed the PDF Viewer (PDF.js) Extension for Chrome. 
I've also tried switching frames:

```
IWebDriver 
driver.SwitchTo().Window(PropertiesCollection.driver.WindowHandles.Last())
```

No luck. Can someone share a working code snippet?

Comment: PDF is not rendered as a document object.  Selenium cannot interact with PDF

Comment: i think the way to go would be using one of PDF libraries (I use one but it's not free) that turns the PDF into an html, then you can either save the html as an html file and navigate to it with selenium or the better option is to load it with HtmlAgilityPack and navigate it that way.  Having said all that, it's still a very ugly process since it uses OCR - random divs, words cut between two different elements, every element is just a tag and styling info so finding a point of reference to navigate through is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox, then PDF document will generally open in another tab. In that case you can use below code(C#) which works fine for me --

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

This will shift focus of Selenium to the last window and there on, you can take a screenshot to validate PDF is generated.